# How do i assign back the DateTime.Now from a string?

Tags: c#, winforms

The code:

```
private void beginOperstionChecker(DateTime dt)
{
    string time = Options_DB.Get_OperationLastTime();
    DateTime.Now = time;
}
```

time now for example show the saved datetime.now could be minute ago or an hour ao.
the datetime.now is saved after my program is finished to make an operation.

dt = the current datetime now i use this method in the constructor.

What i want to do is to calculate the time that have been passed between the last saved datetime.now(time) and the current datetime.now(dt).

If the time that have been passed is 20 minutes or more enable true a button.

Comment: Why do you want to assign `DateTime.Now`? you mean to change system time?

Comment: This would clearly be time travel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot set `DateTime.Now` You need to create an instance of the `DateTime` object.

Then to get the difference you can say

```
TimeSpan diff = DateTime.Now - MyDateTime;
```

This has a property called `TotalMinutes` that you can use for your check.

```
if (diff.TotalMinutes >= 20)
{
   //Do sommething 
}
```

You can try this code

```
DateTime date;
if (DateTime.TryParse(time, out date))
{
    TimeSpan diff = date - dt;
        if (diff.TotalMinutes >= 20)
        {
          //Do sommething 
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Every time you run this method you need to persist the value somewhere. I'm going to call that variable `_lastTime`. That's going to be a `DateTime`. Further, you'll need a variable for the actual elapsed time between those two, we'll call that `_elapsedTime`. That's going to be a `TimeSpan`. With that in mind, consider this code:

```
private void beginOperstionChecker(DateTime dt)
{
    string time = Options_DB.Get_OperationLastTime();
    var dt = DateTime.Parse(time);

    _elapsedTime = dt.Subtract(_elapsedTime);
    _lastTime = dt;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You get an instance of a DateTime from a string using Parse

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(time)
```

and then you get get the time Now using

```
DateTime.UtcNow; or DateTime.Now;
```

and subtract one from the other and format as appropriate for you output

Answer (score 1):

You can check the time elapsed by using the TimeSpan class.

```
private void beginOperstionChecker(DateTime dt)
{ 
    if(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20) == DateTime.Now - dt)
    {
        //do your stuff here
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `TimeSpan`.
 you need to get the `Difference` in `Minutes`

```
DateTime dt1;//get your first date

TimeSpan duration = DateTime.Now - dt1;
if(duration.Minutes>20)
Button1.Enabled=true;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your looking for this:

```
private void beginOperstionChecker(DateTime dt)
{
        string time = Options_DB.Get_OperationLastTime();
        DateTime lastTime  = DateTime.Parse(time);
        if (DateTime.Now - lastTime > new TimeSpan(0, 20, 0))
        {
            //It's passed more than 20mins from last save.
        }
}
```